# Do all zero order reactions occur as combination of multiple elementary reactions?

Tags: kinetics

In a  reaction, the rate determining step (RDS) gives the order of reaction. There might be 2 or 3 molecules colliding to give a product (2nd or 3rd order) or a molecule breaks for order 1. But for zero order reactions, how do they occur? Are all zero order reactions complex (i.e. are there no simple 1 step zero order reactions )

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to get the content of the first line. Could you possibly rewrite it?

Comment: All reaction orders are one smaller if the rate-determining step involves a catalyst with constant, small concentration, so it becomes the limiting factor.